# Tensorflow Lite: bad GPU performance

Tags: android, tensorflow, benchmarking, tensorflow-lite

I'm doing some tests by running a custom model (4 fully-connected layers with 400 units each) on an Android device. I'm testing the runtime performance by using the [Tensorflow Lite Android benchmark application](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement). However, I'm experiencing a very strange behavior: benchmarking the model by using the GPU leads to worst performance than using just the CPUs.

These are the performance with CPUs:

> Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 38.8272, Init: 465, Inference: 38.8438, Overall max resident set size = 0 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = -0.273354 MB

while these are the performance that I obtain by using the GPU:

> Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 418.266, Init: 297403, Inference: 1231.89, Overall max resident set size = 29.2383 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 0.192513 MB

As you can note, the Inference time with GPU is about 4 times the execution time with CPUs. How it is possible?

This is the command that I'm using for benchmarking the model:

```
adb shell am start -S -n org.tensorflow.lite.benchmark/.BenchmarkModelActivity \
--es args '"--graph=<model_path> --num_threads=4 --num_runs=10000 --use_gpu=true"'
```

Comment: On what hardware?

Comment: I've tried 3 different smartphones: Nexus 5, Nexus 6, and a Xiaomi Mi 9T.

Comment: Any suggestion?